# How Kubectl command retrieves the manifest from remote server

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When we run `kubectl apply -k github.com/minio/direct-csi` command, how kubectl downloads and apply the deployment manifest?

How can we download this file to local using `curl` or `wget` command?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the http request that `kubectl` does by using a [verbose log level](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging).

E.g.

```
kubectl get po --v=7
```

Output

```
$ kubectl get po --v=7
I0822 20:08:27.940422   36846 loader.go:375] Config loaded from file:  /Users/Jonas/.kube/config
I0822 20:08:27.958708   36846 round_trippers.go:420] GET https://clusteraddress.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?limit=500
I0822 20:08:27.958736   36846 round_trippers.go:427] Request Headers:
I0822 20:08:27.958742   36846 round_trippers.go:431]     Accept: application/json;as=Table;v=v1beta1;g=meta.k8s.io, application/json
I0822 20:08:27.958747   36846 round_trippers.go:431]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.17.5 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/e0fccaf
I0822 20:08:28.624188   36846 round_trippers.go:446] Response Status: 200 OK in 665 milliseconds
NAME                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nx-67b4f5946c-2z58x   1/1     Running   0          21h
```

> How can we download this file to local using curl or wget command?

You can do the same with e.g. `curl`, everyting in [Kubernetes is a REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/) and you need proper authentication from your `.kube/config` or some else valid authentication.

> what is download from github.com/minio/direct-cs ?

Instead of applying with kustomize (`apply -k`) you can just build the kustomize without applying with this command:

```
kubectl kustomize github.com/minio/direct-csi
```

And you should see all manifests (derived from [kustomization.yaml](https://github.com/minio/direct-csi/blob/master/kustomization.yaml)) in the remote location in a large manifest.

Comment: @jons, thanks, I was interested to know, what is download from `github.com/minio/direct-cs` site? I didn't see any `deployment.yaml` file in this url.

Comment: @sfgroups ah! Instread of `apply -k` you can build the kustomize (without applying) with `kubectl kustomize` like this: `kubectl kustomize github.com/minio/direct-cs` then you see all manifests from that "remote directory" assembled.

Comment: Kustomize is doing transformations of the manifests, so to use e.g. curl, you should also use `kustomize` locally to do the same transformations.

Comment: Got it Thanks for the details.,